# PhpUnit - Expected Status 200 But Received 500

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8, laravel-relations

I have users table with `hasMany` educational backgrounds & educational awards. Then that `educational backgrounds` hasMany educational awards

Here's my `Testcase` when user uploads image my endpoint receives it

```
public function testuploadUsersImageEducationalAwards()
    {
        Storage::fake('public');
        $photo = UploadedFile::fake()->create('photo.png')->size(25000);

        $data = [
            'photo'                     => $photo,
            'award'                     => $this->faker->word,
            'educational_background_id' => EducationalBackground::factory()->create()->id
        ];

        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $response = $this->sendPostRequestToEndpoint($data, 200);

        $data['file_name'] = $response['file_name'];
        unset($data['photo']);

        $response->assertJson($data)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                'id',
                'award',
                'photo',
                'educational_background_id',
                'created_at',
                'updated_at',
            ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users.educational_awards', $data);
    }
```

Here's my endpoint with assert status 200

```
private function sendPostRequestToEndpoint(array $data, $status)
    {
        return $this->json("POST", '/api/users/educational-award/upload-picture', $data)->assertStatus($status);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my `EducationalBackgroundFactory`

```
class EducationalBackgroundFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = EducationalBackground::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'           => User::factory()->create()->id,
            'studies_type'      => $this->faker->randomElement([EducationalBackground::BASIC, EducationalBackground::SECONDARY, EducationalBackground::UNDERGRADUATE, EducationalBackground::GRADUATESCHOOL]),
            'year'              => Carbon::now()->format("Y"),
            'course'            => $this->faker->word,
        ];
    }
}
```

Here's my `EducationalBackground` model

```
class EducationalBackground extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    const BASIC = "basic";
    const SECONDARY = "secondary";
    const UNDERGRADUATE = "undergrad";
    const GRADUATESCHOOL = "grad";

    protected $table = 'users.educational_backgrounds';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'studies_type',
        'year',
        'course',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function educationalAwards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Users\EducationalAward", "educational_background_id");
    }
}
```

Here's my migration

```
public function up()
    {
        
        Schema::create('users.educational_backgrounds', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->enum('studies_type', ['basic', 'secondary', 'undergrad', 'grad']);
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->string('course')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

                
    }
```

Here's my controller code

```
public function uploadUsersImageEducationalAwards(UserImageRequest $request, EducationalBackground $educational_background)
    {
        $uploaded_image = $request->photo->store('users/educational_awards');
        $file_type = $request->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $file = EducationalAward::create([
            'educational_background_id' => $educational_background->id,
            'award'                     => $request->award,
            'photo'                     => $uploaded_image,
        ]);
        return response()->json($file, 200);
    }
```

But this gives me 500 status which i found a way to log error in details. Here's an image for more clarity

[image]

Comment: id = upload-picture??

Comment: yes but pass parameter of $data. i dont understand why its like that.

Comment: You post a image so the handle of the database is at your controller. I don't think is test problem. Can you post the code from back end? If you don't see any error at your logs most probably have a try catch and never returned it

Comment: sure bro. give me a sec.

Comment: You use the trait withoutMidleware in your test class or base class ?

Comment: I have middleware in my controller. In my test class none. If i understand this question correctly.

Comment: Also not using any traits in my test class or controller class.

Comment: Your issue is the generated `EducationalBackground`'s `id`. It is returning a string `upload-picture` when it should be an `integer`...

Can you share the `EducationalBackground` factory and model, and the `EducationalBackground` migration?

Comment: Hello thank you for taking time to answer, never thought that maybe that's where the error is. This gives me more broader perspective. I've updated the post with factory, models and migration for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

remove unset function before sending response.

Comment: Hello bro sorry it took me long to realize. I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of hours. Haven't realized quickly what your saying. As you told i've removed the unset. Still gives me same error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).